# How do I quickly convey the concept of organising the cloud using images?

Tags: gui-design

I am working on https://datkey.com, and the UI design and UX aren't working out.

How do I build a good quick set of images for a simple splash page or convey quickly to the users the concept of organizing their cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The graphic design is outdated. [People make impressions about your website within the first 50 ms](http://webwinners.info/articles/copywriting/50-Milliseconds-Is-All-It-Takes-To-Make-Up-Your-Mind/2117305). Within the first 50 ms, I thought, "this site looked like it was designed in the 90's and I'm not willing to forfeit my time over to it."
2. You don't make good use of imagery to quickly teach people what's the purpose of your website. You make heavy use of the logos of Facebook, Linkin, and Twitter, but that doesn't tell me much. Instead, you should be showing screenshots of what people actually do on your site.
3. Your hierarchical structure is not clear. There's too many font sizes and colors for anyone to discern a pattern on the structure.
4. Using images for text is bad for readability. If people with poor vision or people with super high density screens need to enlarge the text, your textual images will just become blurrier as the get bigger.
5. It's not clear what your site does. All the text is very vague.

Comment: All great points. In the first 50ms, I thought: "there's nothing but a blue line here". Luckily I gave it a bit longer before leaving the site :-)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question...

Comment: I have updated datkey.com using these ideas thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I would add to Jojo' answer that :

1. Interaction possibilities are very low and do not appear clearly.
2. Low information content. User generaly want to click somewhere to have more information about what he sees. Here, he can't. It looks like you have nothing to say.
3. Clicking on the links at the bottom brings you to another page, totally different from the previous one  and without any "go back" link. And that is really a bad practice. You should have some navigation consistency. Why don't you have a top    main menu ?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question...

Answer (score 3):

In order to explain the concept I think you're on the right track with "Browse, collect, share". Those steps in the workflow logically follow each other, and are not too difficult to understand. Your current design is inconsistent though: the total control box uses a different order (organize, share, browse) that doesn't make sense.

**1) Browse** (with supporting icons for the social media sources - I don't need to know that I can share both my tweets and followed tweets, just twitter/linkedin/facebook/youtube/google is enough at this point)

**2) Organize** (what does that mean in your case? is it folders? sorting? labels? annotations? use either a clear image that illustrates the process or a screenshot of sorted items)

**3) Share** (with images about sharing)

Play a little with those 3 items (boxes, arrows, numbered steps, ...) and I'm sure you can come up with something.

Answer (score -1):

I support JoJo's opinion. What I have to add is:

1. There is plenty of space for main menu at the top between logo and login part;
2. I miss the registration link so I could join smoothly when coming for first time at the site;
3. I think there is too much graphical information (icons + text). I personally would prefer it to be one solid image explaining the whole idea or see a link to a detailed manual of use, etc.

I hope that is helpful to you.